# how to mark rows as readonly in extjs4 grid?

Tags: grid, extjs4

how can i lock the rows in editable grid?

Based on one of the parameter of the store i want to configure the grid to show lock symbol against the row and lock those rows to mark them as read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an symbol to a row depending on a row (record) field you can use a [renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) for this column or a new symbol column, something like this :

```js
columns : [{
    header : 'Locked',
    dataIndex : 'locked',
    renderer : function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
        if (record.data.locked == true) {
            return '<img src="img/lockedIcon.jpg">';
        } else {
            return '<img src="img/freeIcon.jpg">';
        }
     }
}]
```

To avoid editing on a row you could register to the [beforedit](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing-event-beforeedit) event of the editor plugin. To prevent editing just cancel the event someway like this:

```js
onBeforeEdit : function(object, options) {
    if (object.record.locked == true) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // do what is needed to start editing
    }
}
```

**Edit:** You could also use a store param instead of a record field, but this would make locking grid wide instead of per row basis.

Comment: Thanks for answer suknic, i had already implemented using the same mechanism. however, I found multiple ways to achieve the same on sencha guid - http://www.sencha.com/learn/grid-faq/ They have provided options of disabling cell editing, row editing, column editing.